# UItextfield in UIScrollView and move cursor with magnifying glass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have about 3 `UITextfield` in a `UIScrollview`. When I touch and hold magnifying glass and move cursor in "textfield", my "scrollview" also scroll together. I need to disable scrolling of `UIScrollview` when user use magnifying glass to move cursor in `UITextfield`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to the UITextViews. In the function corresponding to the gesture disable scrolling in the UIScrollView